# .NET price format issue

Tags: .net, cultureinfo

In .net VB have a multi-lingual and multi-currency price listing that comes from two sources. For prices coming from our SQL server where prices are held as a Money datatype, all is well if we change languages. i.e. US$599.00 in English is displayed as US$599,00 in Italian.

Currency and price are separate fields, btw.

However, when the data source is from our partners web service when the data is a string, then US$599.00 is still correct in English but when in Italian, Spanish or German it is US$599.00,00. I can't work out what's going wrong with it. Not all prices are full units so I can't just parse an integer.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: So to recap: you're having trouble parsing the string `"US$599.00"` to a decimal?

Comment: Nope. The string from the web service is "599.00". If I Convert.ToDecimal(theString) I still get 599.00,00 when displayed in the datagrid output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The string from the web service is "599.00". If I Convert.ToDecimal(theString) I still get 599.00,00 when displayed in the datagrid output.

If the string from the web service *always* uses a dot as decimal separator, convert using the [InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx), which has a `.` as `DecimalSeparator`:

```
decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal("559.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks, this sorted it out nicely.